# Can someone explain (in detail) how the various options in a Dagger @Module annotation work and interact with each other?

Tags: java, android, dagger

I see some documentation and blogs, but nothing that pulls it all together.  If that exists, a pointer to that might be sufficient.

I *think* I understand some of the basics, but please correct me if I am wrong.

1. library = true means Dagger should verify that every @Provides in a
   module is used to inject something in the the list of classes listed
   in the injects = { ... } list
2. library = false disables this check, becuase maybe you use this
   module in several places/projects and not every @Provides is used.
3. complete = true means that this module can satisfy **all** of the
   dependencies needed for all the classes listed in the injects = {
   ... }

I don't understand how includes and addsTo work, and how they can (or even should) be used to enable setting complete = true.

For example,  say I create an initial graph by using

`ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(moduleA, moduleB);`

and then I extend that graph using ModuleC.

```
ObjectGraph extendedGraph = graph.plus(new ModuleA());
```

It seems to me that the graph was constructed from ModuleA and ModuleB, so I would want to say ModuleC addsTo **both** ModuleA and ModuleB, but addsTo only allows one.

Should we say that ModuleC includes ModuleA and ModuleB and then say ModuleC is complete?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best resource I can find, unfortunately their continues to be be open items to more clearly document each annotation.

https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/370

Comment: This definitely helps

Comment: Yeah - we've focused on Dagger 2.x which changes a lot of how these pieces all interact, and will be putting more effort into documenting that.  We should start rolling things out this quarter or early next.